# Getting error while starting ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, sh

Every time I start my system I received this message:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:
/etc/profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ('
/etc/profile: line 1:iamgreat# /etc/profile: system-wide.profile file for the Bourne shell(sh(1))'

As a result the session will not be configured correctly You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

Can Someone please help me fix this issue?
These are my current contents of `/etc/profile`:

```sh
iamgreat# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1)) 
 # and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
if [ "$PS1" ]; then  
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then    
  # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.    
  # PS1='\h:\w\$ '    
  if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then      
      . /etc/bash.bashrc    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then      
      PS1='# '
    else
       PS1='$ '    
      fi
    fi 
 fi

 # The default umask is now handled by pam_umask. 
 # See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then  
   for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do    
      if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done  
   unset i
 fi

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: @david Sorry, I am new to ubuntu with really less experience. I am unable to undersatand what you are advising me. Are you asking me to open my etc/profile and post its contents? . So can you please explain what i need to do.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: This is not a fatal error which prevents the OP from logging in. The message tells you that the configuration may be incorrect. In this case it's a syntax error, so neither `/etc/profile` nor files in `/etc/profile.d` were sourced. There is no need for any live DVD etc.

Comment: Yes, @Ashutosh, please post the contents of `/etc/profile` by editing your question. Then somebody can explain how it should be corrected.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Ok. I thought "getting error" (see title) meant that OP cannot boot their system successfully.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: It is an error, but it's an error when a bash process started by lightdm tries to source `/etc/profile`. The main process is not interrupted, so the login proceeds. (I happen to know it since I wrote the code which triggers the message dialog.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/etc/profile` is a mess. Even after [the removal of the stray `iamgreat` at the beginning](/a/731942/175814), `sh -n` still complained about a syntax error. After re-indentation and sanitation of white-space, the error was gone. Here's the result:

```sh
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Replace the content of your `/etc/profile` with the code listed above (e. g. with `gksu gedit /etc/profile`) and you should be good again.

P.S.: `/etc/environment` is a better place than `/etc/profile` for global environment variables like `JAVA_HOME` (see last line).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> iamgreat# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
> ```

You shouldn't have that `iamgreat` there. Remove it. You can use this command to do so:

```
sudo sed -i '1s/^iamgreat//' /etc/profile
```

Or use an editor.