# startup popup error: error found when loading /etc/profile

Tags: 16.04, unity, login, startup, .profile

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with default Unity window manager and I started getting this popup error right after I login (only when starting up the computer after shutdown; I do not get the error if I suspend and login again). I cannot access the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1..12]</kbd> tty's: I only get a black screen and no login/text See the popup here:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

[image: error popup]

I tried all the possible solutions I could: I reset my `/etc/profile` to default (from "[Getting error while starting ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731475/getting-error-while-starting-ubuntu-14-04)"), I added `nomodeset` to GRUB, etc, but nothing helps. I also found that I do not have a file `~/.profile` if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Best suggestion I have is to boot from the Live CD/USB, mount the filesystem and then edit /etc/profile.

You may also be able to add init=/bin/sh (same place you would have put nomodeset) and then run "mount -n -o remount,rw /" to get the root filesystem writable.  Fix /etc/profile and then reboot.

At a guess, most likely you have a command in /etc/profile that is trying to call out to sudo.  You can potentially just comment that out.